# how to use axios helper setToken inside .onRequest interceptor

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js, jwt

I am using both [nuxt-auth](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/recipes/extend.html) and [nuxt-axios](https://axios.nuxtjs.org) modules. 
I want to intercept every axios requests and check if my JWT access token is almost expired, if so, I want to update it.
I the wrote a small extension to **nuxt-auth** as follow. My problem is that , once I get the new Token, `$auth.setToken(strategy,newToken)` and `$axios.setToken(newToken)` don't seem to make the expected updates.
How then should I be using the interceptors and helpers ? I'm not sure it's the right place/way to use them

```js
var jwtDecode = require("jwt-decode")

export default function({$auth, $axios}) {
  const strategy = "local"

  $axios.onRequest( async(config) => {
    if ($auth.loggedIn) {
      let refreshToken = "some confidtion"

      if (refreshToken) {
        try {
          await refreshAccessURL()
        } catch (error) {
          return Promise.reject(error)
        }
      }
    }
    return config
  })

  async function refreshAccessURL() {
    const refresh = $auth.getRefreshToken(strategy)
    try {
      const { access } = await $axios.$post(refreshURL, { refresh })
      const newToken = "Bearer " + access
      $auth.setToken(strategy, newToken)
      $axios.setToken(newToken)

      return newToken

    } catch (e) {
      $auth.logout()
      throw new Error(e)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can add interceptor like below inside `plugins/axios.js`

```
export default function({ $axios }) {
  $axios.onRequest((config) => {
     config.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer abc`;
  });
}
```

Comment: I actually want **auth**  to be availbale inside my interceptor (that's why I made a plugin for nuxt-auth rather than for axios.   
Question by the way, what's the difference between using `config.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer abc' ` or `$axios.setToken(newToken)` ?

Comment: if you see the doc for `setToken` (https://axios.nuxtjs.org/helpers.html#settoken) it internally does the same this like `headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer abc'`
When I tried to use `setToken` I was also not successful due to some internal error of `nuxt/axios`